# Which sentence is right: "On Saturdays I play video games." vs "I play video games on Saturdays"?

Tags: grammar, sentence, time

Which sentence is correct:

1. On Saturdays I play video games.
2. I play video games on Saturdays.

I think that both are correct but I got this sentence as incorrect in a test.

I searched the web for examples and found phrases where the time is placed at the beginning and at the end:

- **On New Year’s Day**, the whole family gets together.
- The folk festival is always held **on the last weekend in July**.

Comment: They're both correct.  Nit-pickers might insist in a comma after "Saturdays" in the first case, but with and without are both idiomatic.

Comment: Six of one, half-dozen of the other. Imagine, if you will, reciting basically the same sentence over and over again for each day of the week (e.g., I play video games on Saturday. I play hopscotch on Sunday. I play dominoes on Monday. I play cribbage on Tuesday. And so on.) To mix things up a bit you could have 3 or 4 ways of saying similar things (e.g., Tuesdays are for pool. Letter-writing is reserved for Wednesday. Thursday is for Texas hold-em. And so on). Variety, they say, is the spice of life. Rhetoric ain't just for persuadin'! Don

Comment: Both are correct. Both are common constructions. Whoever quizzed you is nitpicking at breakneck pace.

Comment: They are both correct standing alone like this. Is it possible, however, that on your test these sentences were preceded by questions? That might narrow down your choice. For example, "What do you do on Saturdays?" "On Saturdays, I play video games." Or another example, "When do you play video games?" "I play video games on Saturdays." That said, both would still be correct grammatically, and both would be strongly influenced by intonation. But if you were given those questions on the test, the examiners might have been looking for you to make the subtle distinction in the responses.